# H2 database WebServer session timeout

Tags: session, webserver, timeout, h2

How can I change the session length of the H2 database WebServer? I'm using it only for development on my local machine and the default 30 minutes session length is too short as it often times out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you would need to change the source code of H2, as the session timeout is hardcoded. The class is `org.h2.server.web.WebServer`, the constant is `SESSION_TIMEOUT`.

In the next version of H2, this will be configurable.

Comment: Hi Thomas, is it possible now? I found [SysProperties Javadoc](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/SysProperties.html) and tried running h2 with `-Dh2.consoleTimeout=5000`. It doesn't seem to work as I get `JdbcSQLException : Feature not supported`.

Comment: @ChiffShinz the system property is something you set when starting the process, that is "java -Dh2.consoleTimeout=5000 ...". You can't possibly get an exception when setting a system property :-)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Normally I use `java -jar h2-1.4.196.jar` via cmd to start H2. Now i just appended `-Dh2.consoleTimeout=5000` behind the command. This gave me the `JdbcSQLException : Feature not supported`.

Comment: @ChiffShinz system properties are set as follows: `java -Dh2.consoleTimeout=5000 -jar h2-1.4.196.jar`. This is not related to H2, it's the way Java works.

Comment: Oh yes of course, how dumb of me. Got it working now - thank you very much!

Comment: @ThomasMueller - Has there been any particular reason for designing this property to be set in milliseconds?